# How can I create a web-to-leads form that will also create an opportunity?

Tags: web2lead

We are trying to create booking forms for our website that connect to our client's salesforce system. They want to have the booking show up as an opportunity. The website uses Drupal. I am using the Web-to-Lead form and then trying to create a process in the Process Builder that will create an Opportunity at the same time.

I have created a custom lead field to be used for the Opportunity name. While the lead generates without issue, the opportunity still does not populate. Additionally, the email field in the web-to-lead form seems to activating an email alert that would go back to the user stating that the lead has been assigned to the user.

Comment: Hi Miki, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Your post is much more likely to receive prompt, useful feedback if you articulate a clear question within. Saying "I am at a loss" does not help people pinpoint exactly where you stuck. Much better to *ask* something like *Why is my `Lead` not associated to an `Opportunity`?* Or perhaps *How can I remove this email alert?* Right now it's hard to tell what you're confused about/trying to fix.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the feedback and the assistance.

Comment: My goal is to use the web-to-lead form to trigger the creation of an opportunity using the process builder. Doesn't changing my verbiage here then change my goals and what I am trying to do?

Comment: If you have any clarifications to add, please **[edit]** them into your post. That's not what comments are for. Requesting clarification is fine, but providing it is less useful and more likely to just be missed entirely by the casual reader.

Answer (score 1):

I have got around the issues that a web to lead can only create leads before.

What I did was use a web to lead form and stored all the information in a lead. I then had a trigger that took that new lead and created a record in my desired object. Once this was done the trigger then delete the lead.

It works quite well

Answer (score 0):

Web to Lead is nothing but a public web service which is hosted by SF which handles lead creation for your org. If you want web to custom object then you have to expose web services which would again be developer thing.

Another option is to use this app exchange product "Web to Any".

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000DlGucUAF

Am not affiliated to the above product but have used it personally so would recommend.

Comment: So using it in combination with the Process Builder is not possible?

Comment: Please include the name of this package and clearly indicate if you are or are not affiliated.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I am not sure I understand. I am looking for assistance with using Salesforces web-to-lead form to trigger a process in the process builder. What does "affiliated" mean?

Comment: @Miki this feedback has nothing to do with you and is intended for Pranay only.

Answer (score 0):

I think Joe's suggestion of a trigger is the cleanest and most sophsitcated approach you could take, but if you were set on using a process builder, I believe it could be done without much issue ASSUMING that you have some field to differentiate lead sources.

My thought would be to create a process builder that fires on the creation of a record of the lead type. I would then setup the first check to make sure that the source of the lead was in fact a web to lead form, most likely through checking against the lead source field.

For the actions of this check, create a new action to create an opportunity record. From here, you can pull the values from the Lead record that was created from web2lead and put them onto your new opportunity record.

This should give you an opportunity from every lead that comes in from web to lead, though you should be sure that your web to lead records are the ONLY ones using the lead source you are checking for to avoid incorrect creation of opps.